# list item to database

Tags: c#, .net, database, list, generic-list

i have a list

```
List<SalesDetail>  SalesList = new List<SalesDetail>();
SalesDetail detail = new SalesDetail();
```

where "SalesDetail" is a class. i have a button (add) and  my code on click event of add button is 
    SalesList.Add(details);
where details is object of class SalesDetail which contains public variables with {set; and get;}

but when i try to retrieve each item of the list then i only get the last item.
my code retrieving each item is

```
foreach(SalesDetail sd in SalesList)
{

    messageBox.show(SalesList);

}
```

in my class SalesDetail i have following code

```
Public string Brand{get; set;}
Public string Product{get; set;}
```

i want to retrieve each item from list and save it to database
i would like to know where i have made mistake while retrieving the data.. 
please help
Regards
bunzitop

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `sd` object which refers to the current item in `SalesList`

Try:

```
foreach(SalesDetail sd in SalesList)
{

    messageBox.show(sd.Brand);
    messageBox.show(sd.Product);

}
```

From chat:

```
List<SalesDetail> SalesList = new List<SalesDetail>();

public void button1_click() {

    SalesDetail detail = new SalesDetail();
    detail.Brand = textBox1.Text
    detail.Product= textBox2.Text` 
    SalesList.Add(detail);

}
```

Comment: i tried as per you said but error message comes "cannot convert to string " and i also tried sd.ToString() but it also didn't showed any items of the list..

Comment: i add my items to list with code
    `SalesList.Add(details);`
and details is object of class which contains 
    `Public string Brand {Set; Get;}`
   ` Public String Product {set; Get;}`
is my way of adding to list correct??

Comment: Try sd.Brand and sd.Product

Comment: i tried 
 `sd.Brand`
 too but each time in loop this gives me the last entered item only,,, m unable to get the others items still.. :(

Comment: @user2174542 it sounds like your SalesList does not have all of the items you expect.  Put a breakpoint in the foreach loop and inspect SalesList and see what items it contains, check if they are different or all the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26945/discussion-between-bunzitop-and-darren-davies)

Answer (score 2):

`SalesList` is the type. You should use `sd` (which is the changing value) in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your class definition is wrong since you omitted the types of your `Brand` and `Product` properties and the `public` visibility modifier should be lowercase.

In order to use `ToString()` you will need to override to the method in your class:

```
public class SalesDetail
{
    public string Brand {get; set;}
    public string Product {get; set;}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Brand: {0}, Product {1}", Brand, Product);
    }
}
```

Then you can use Linq to [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx) the list and display it contents.

```
var items = SalesList.Select(s => s.ToString()).Aggregate((s, s1) => s + Environment.NewLine + s1);
MessageBox.Show(items);
```